# javax.validation.ValidationException: %class% has already be configured in xml

Tags: java, bean-validation, nhibernate-validator

There's a bean validation in a project's jar which validation.xml contains field-level validation of Address bean.

The other project uses Address class and needs to have specific Address validation. So extended-validation.xml was created with class-level validation of Address bean.

As a result, during the app deployment, ValidationException occures: `javax.validation.ValidationException: my.base.datatypes.Address has already be configured in xml.`.

Here are two validation xml files with basic validation and "extended validation".

validation.xml

```
<bean class="my.base.datatypes.Address" ignore-annotations="true">
    <getter name="country">
        <constraint annotation="my.imp.services.validation.ValidCode">
            <message>{msg01}</message>
            <groups>
                <value>my.imp.services.validation.ImportGroup</value>
            </groups>
            <element name="name">Country</element>
        </constraint>
    </getter>
</bean>
```

extended-validation.xml

```
<bean class="my.base.datatypes.Address" ignore-annotations="true">
    <class ignore-annotations="true">
        <constraint annotation="my.extended.imp.services.validation.ValidAddress">
            <message>ERROR DURING ADDRESS VALIDATION</message>
            <groups>
                <value>my.imp.services.validation.ImportGroup</value>
            </groups>
        </constraint>
    </class>
</bean>
```

Is it possible to extend already existing validation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution appears to be very simple and trivial. If you want to extend validation rules, use different validator which will load `extended-validation.xml` constraints configuration. In this case, base validator validates data according to `validation.xml` config, and another validator validates data according to `extended-validation.xml` config. So no more config collisions occur.